# Relating Moments to OLS

Tags: least-squares, moments

I am trying to see the relationship between OLS and Method of Moments.

**Moment Equation:** For a discrete random variable and a continuous random variable centered around some point "c":

$$E[(X-c)^n] = \sum_{x \in X} (x-c)^n \cdot P(X=x)$$

$$E[(X-c)^n] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x-c)^n f(x) dx$$

**Method of Moments:** For a $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ from a population with a distribution that is defined by some parameters $\theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_p$, the method of moments estimator of $\theta_i$ is obtained by setting the $i^{th}$ sample moment equal to the $i^{th}$ population moment, and solving for $\theta_i$ (for $i = 1, 2, ..., p$.):

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j^i = E[X^i]$$

**Moment Conditions:** In the applied sense (for estimation), we equate theoretical moments to the applied moments based on moment conditions. For example, if $X$ follows a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, the moment conditions are:

$$E[X] = \mu$$
$$E[(X-\mu)^2] = \sigma^2$$

**OLS Regression:** This is my basic summary of OLS [$(y - X\beta)^T(y - X\beta)$ is the matrix way of representing Sum of Squared Errors]:

$$y = X\beta + \epsilon$$
$$\hat{\beta} = \arg\min_{\beta} (y - X\beta)^T(y - X\beta)$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} (y - X\beta)^T(y - X\beta) = 0$$

To solve, we can write:
$$f(\beta) = (y - X\beta)^T(y - X\beta) =  y^Ty - \beta^TX^Ty - y^TX\beta + \beta^TX^TX\beta$$
$$f(\beta) = y^Ty - 2\beta^TX^Ty + \beta^TX^TX\beta$$
$$\frac{\partial f(\beta)}{\partial \beta} = -2X^Ty + 2X^TX\beta$$
$$-2X^Ty + 2X^TX\beta = 0$$
$$X^TX\beta = X^Ty$$
$$\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$

**From here, I am trying to see where the connection between OLS and Method of Moments comes in.**

I read online that we need some moment conditions - we can use the following conditions as they are typically used in linear regression (e.g. independence of residuals and covariates, 0 correlation amongst errors)

$$E[\epsilon] = 0$$
$$E[X\epsilon] = 0$$

Since we know that $\epsilon =  y - X\beta$, we can make this substitution into the second moment condition (and re-arrange):

$$E[X\epsilon] = E[X(y - X\beta)] = 0$$
$$E[Xy] - E[XX^T\beta] = 0$$
$$E[Xy] = E[XX^T]\beta$$

Now we equate the sample and population moments together ($\frac{1}{n}$ comes from the general Expectation Formula):

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iy_i = \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iX_i^T\right)\hat{\beta}_{MM}$$
$$\hat{\beta}_{MM} = \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iX_i^T\right)^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iy_i\right) = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty = \hat{\beta}_{OLS}$$

So we can see that OLS provides the same estimate as Method of Moments.

But how is the first moment condition being used? Is this required for the variance estimation?

Comment: You are only finding one vector of parameters ($\beta$) so given a full rank $XX^T$ you would only need the equations defined by $\mathbb{E}[X\varepsilon] = 0$ for OLS to be the method of moments estimator. Note that the method of moments estimator doesn't have the same asymptotic properties that an M-estimator would so merely showing that something is an MOM estimator doesn't give many theoretically guarantees on performance.

Comment: can you please explain what is an M-estimator? Is OLS an M-Estimator?

Comment: M-estimators are estimators where the objective function (i.e. the function we optimise over) is a sample sum or average. Least-squares estimators are M-estimators, as we are minimising the sum of squares. Maximum-likelihood estimators are also M-estimators, as the log-likelihood can be expressed as a sum.

Comment: Wow, it seems most estimators are M estimators  - yes?